# Compare date to today's date and return number of days

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I am using MySQL.

I am trying to compare a date that is in a datetime field to today's date and return the number of days difference [i.e. today - column = no. of days]

Is that possible? How would I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we need more information from your side, like the query you are using and what you tried so far, but maybe this can help you out:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF('2014-02-20 00:00:00', NOW()); //return 7
```

In this case, you should add a 'FROM table' and replace the date in this query to the `datetime` column. Something like this:

```
SELECT 
    DATEDIFF(datetimefield, NOW())
FROM
    tablename
```

Comment: Thank you, all of these answers worked, since they're all the same! 
In the end had to have three arguments for DateDiff so used: 

SELECT DATEDIFF(day, column_name, GetDate()) AS column_name FROM table

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use DATEDIFF function

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(NOW(), date_column)
```

It should return the number of days between now and your column.

Comment: Cool - I am now getting the error NOW() is not an inbuilt function. Is there another function I should/could use?

Comment: Used GetDate instead but it says that DateDiff needs three arguments?

Comment: Are you using MySQL? There should be both functions available.

Answer (score 1):

You must use [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

```
DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2)
```

`DATEDIFF()` returns `expr1 – expr2` expressed as a value in days from one date to the other. `expr1` and `expr2` are date or date-and-time expressions.